# Не правильно заполняется таблица в бд

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Дела обстоят так: дошел до момента добавления друзей в своей Соц сети, решил использовать многие ко многим (many to many from asp.net core), создал необходимую сущность и прописал логику в контексте, создал таблицу в бд,в таблице 2 ячейки, ячейка userid и freindis, прохожусь точкой останова, все идет как положено, все данные получаю и записываю как надо, однако по факту в обе ячейки ложится айдишник юзера и в первую и во вторую...
Теперь код:

```
public class Friends
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int FriendId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }



    }
```

создаю список у юзера:

```
public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            UserFriends = new List<Friends>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Friends> UserFriends { get; set; }
    }
```

котекст дб:

```
public class DBUserContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DBUserContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.FriendId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(s => s.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(c => c.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.FriendId);
        }
```

метод который собственно все и делает:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{id}"), Route("getfriend")]
        public IActionResult GetFriend(int id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            User thisus = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            thisus.UserFriends.Add(new Friends { UserId = thisus.Id, FriendId = user.Id });
            db.Update(thisus);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

ну и результат:
UserId 4
FriendId 4
хотя френд должен быть 2...

Answer (score 0):

Рано забил тревогу пардонте, немного неправильно записал в контекст, было так:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.FriendId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(s => s.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(c => c.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.FriendId);
        }
```

стало так:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.FriendId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
            .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
            .WithMany(s => s.UserFriends)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.FriendId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
            .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
            .WithMany(c => c.UserFriends)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.UserId);
    }
```

и все стало ок, решил не удалять вопрос, мб кому будет полезным, но если админ настоит то удалю без проблем:)